# How authenticate to an API with SSL certificate?

Tags: node.js, api, ssl, certificate, pem

I need to access to the API of a service provider (for my company)
So, they gave me a 'doc' and a SSL certificate in multiple form (.jks, .p12, .pem)
I work with NodeJS so I took the .pem, inside there is 2 certificates and 1 encrypted private key.

I split the .pem in 3 files, mycert.crt.pem, mycert.key.pem, mycert2.crt.pem
(I checked on https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html to know which cert use with the key)

So my NodeJS, I used the least possible module to avoid module problem :

```js
const cert = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('cert', 'mycert.crt.pem'))
const key = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('cert', 'mycert.key.pem'))

let options = {
    hostname: 'https://serviceproviderurl.com',
    path: 'v1/api/example',
    method: 'POST',
    key: key,
    cert: cert
}

let req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    console.log(res.statusCode)
    res.on('data', function (d) {
      process.stdout.write(d)
    })
})
req.end()
```

And the error message :

```
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:151:17)
    at Object.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1407:48)
    at Agent.createConnection (https.js:125:22)
    at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:234:26)
    at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:193:10)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:276:16)
    at Object.request (https.js:309:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Project/test.js:74:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10) {
  opensslErrorStack: [
    'error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey:ASN1 lib',
    'error:2306A075:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_item_decrypt_d2i:pkcs12 pbe crypt error',
    'error:23077074:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pbe_crypt:pkcs12 cipherfinal error'
  ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  function: 'EVP_DecryptFinal_ex',
  reason: 'bad decrypt',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_BAD_DECRYPT'
```

I think I missed something with the 3 certificates. Also they didn't gave me a passphrase, is it normal ?
I don't have a good knowledge about SSL certificate use and I hope you can help me.

Thank you